# gem server: How to update gems with missing rdoc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, rubygems

I really like `gem server` command which bootstraps the webserver with local RubyGems Documentation Index.

The only problem I have: some gems don't have rdoc files.

How can I add missing rdoc(all gems are mainstream gems, not my own)?

---

Installed via Bundler; Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate all rdoc of all of your gem with command :

```
gem rdoc --all
```