# Loading unsafe YAMLs with YAML/Store in Psych 4

Tags: ruby, yaml

A recent change in Ruby's YAML Library (Psych 4) causes "unsafe" YAMLs to fail if they contain aliases, or try to instantiate unspecified classes. This is discussed in multiple places, like [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191685/visit-psych-nodes-alias-unknown-alias-default-psychbadalias).

I am trying to figure out how to tell the derivative [`yaml/store`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) library to allow loading unsafe YAMLs, or to provide it with my list of allowed classes.

The documentation is scarce as far as I could find, and after reading it, this is the only logical attempt I could come up with:

```rb
require 'date'
require 'yaml/store'

# 1. These options work perfectly with YAML.load_file, but not with YAML::Store
# 2. These options are not needed in Psych < 4.0
yaml_opts = { aliases: true, permitted_classes: [Time, Date, Symbol] }

store = YAML::Store.new 'log.yml', yaml_opts
data = store.transaction { store[:entries] }
p data
```

using this YAML file:

```yaml
# log.yml
:entries:
- :timestamp: 2018-07-09 00:00:00.000000000 +03:00
  :action: Comment
  :comment: Started logging
```

This fails with Psych 4, and succeeds with Psych 3.

```rb
# Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'psych', '>= 4.0'    # fail
# gem 'psych', '< 4.0'   # pass
```

As a related anecdote, the example demonstrated in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html), also fails as-is when trying to load it with `store.transaction { store["people"] }`

Answer (score 10):

Although this is not the proper way of doing things, until there is a better answer, I found that adding the below code fixes the problem.

```rb
module YAML
  class << self
    alias_method :load, :unsafe_load
  end
end
```

This simply restores the underlying `YAML::load` method to its 3.x behavior of `unsafe_load` instead of `safe_load`.

In cases where my YAMLs come from a trusted source (100% of my use cases), I do not see any benefit in the new Psych 4 behavior, and feel it is ok (although awkward) to revert it.

The relevant source code reference is [the 3.3.2 → 4.0.0 diff](https://my.diffend.io/gems/psych/3.3.2/4.0.0)