# Psych will not install when using a bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle, psych

I am trying to update some gems in my rails app and I get the error below when a gem called psych 5.0.2.
I have seen similar reports of this issue on some sites but nothing that helped me. Any help would be appreciated.

Versions: Windows 10, Ruby: 3.05, Rails: 7.0.0 (just changed from 5.2.2), Bundler: 2.2.33

```
Using stringio 3.0.4
Fetching psych 5.0.2
Installing psych 5.0.2 with native extensions
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.2-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.2-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.2-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-libyaml-0.2.2-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/psych-5.0.2/ext/psych
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
./siteconf20230120-15584-xuwv0b.rb extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: The error message you are seeing is related to a dependency of the psych gem, specifically the `libyaml` library. This library is necessary for the `psych gem` to function properly, but it does not appear to be present on your system.

One option is to manually install the `libyaml` library on your system before installing the `psych gem`.

Another option is to install an earlier version of the psych gem that lacks this dependence. This may be accomplished by specifying the version in your `Gemfile`, such as this `gem 'psych', '5.0.0'`, and then executing bundle install again.

Comment: Thanks @Adif_Sgaid.   I added  ```gem 'psych', '~>3.0'``` which seemed to solve the problem, following advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346369/ruby-3-overcommit-psych-issue.   So your suggestion of installing an earlier version of the psych app is spot on.   I never thought I had to add the psych app as it was already included in Ruby 3.05.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/home/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib pkg-config --exists yaml-0.1
package configuration for yaml-0.1 is not found`  on `Almalinux`.  I can't install it either, as it says it's already installed.

Answer (score -1):

"Hey fellow Windows developers!

To get your server up and running smoothly, follow these simple steps:

1. First, install 'psych' gem by running:

```
gem install psych
```

2. Next, execute:

```
bundle install
```

3. Finally, fire up your Rails server with:

```
rails s
```

That's it! Your server will be happily running in no time. Happy coding!"

Comment: Why is this quoted? Did you perhaps copy this from somewhere?