# not able to install rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

hey I'm trying to install rails for a project I'm working on

```
gem install rails
```

but i get this error

```
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/smith/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.1.1/ext/psych
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Users/smith/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.1.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/smith/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/smith/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.1.1/gem_make.out
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/smith/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
```

I'm trying to get rails to work but forsome reason it not iis there any step on fixing this I try other stack overflow method but it still haven't work like the proxy and create devkit for ruby

Comment: It seems that your system is missing the libyaml. Perhaps this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75200760/psych-will-not-install-when-using-a-bundle-install

Comment: @zaphodbln_ I try this but still it show that yaml.h isn’t available

Comment: I followed the guidelines on this link: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/msys2 and it was quite helpful. Essentially, after installing ruby, you  will need to enable the ruby interations within the linux emulator tool (MinGW in most cases) by running the following the command `ridk install 2 3`

Comment: Just run the command as administrator

Answer (score 1):

For me, I simply updated the gem using
`gem update --system`
, executed the command prompt as an administrator, and then installed Rails with `gem install rails`

Comment: Answer solution does not apply to the answer