# Error on ruby upgrade to 3.1.2 from 3.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-3.1

I am trying to upgrade my app Ruby version to 3.1.2 from 3.0.2 but it shows this error `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Unknown alias: default (Psych::BadAlias)`. Could someone guide me how to solve this error. I tried `gem rdoc --all` and `bundle update`.
Also I tried adding the psych gem with version <4 but it leads to other error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191685/visit-psych-nodes-alias-unknown-alias-default-psychbadalias/71503264#71503264

Comment: I tried that and its showed `bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require: cannot load such file -- rack-protection (LoadError)` 

`gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in require`

Answer (score 0):

Check which gem throws the error and upgrade it to the latest version.

Ruby 3.1 uses Psych 4 while the 3.0 uses Psych 3.

Latest version of Bootsnap works fine with Ruby 3.1.2